# Can't Get Python To Parse JSON From Site

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my Python script to parse some data (the price) from a specific json file on a site, but I am unable to get it working.
It can extract the whole page fine, but it cannot extract certain data just by itself.

Here is the JSON I am trying to extract data from:

```
[{
    "id": 1696146,
    "name": "Genos",
    "photo_url": "https://hobbydb-production.s3.amazonaws.com/processed_uploads/collectible_photo/collectible_photo/image/324461/1556082253-24867-7610/Genos_Vinyl_Art_Toys_60fb245b-1af9-4ad1-a5a2-c90d3e8291a6_medium.jpg",
    "preorder": false,
    "price": "$40.00",
    "price_after_discount": "$40.00",
    "seller_username": "BatmanPajamas",
    "url": "https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/2/cart/1696146"
}]
```

Here is the code I have got that allows me to get the entire json:

```
import urllib.request, json 
withurllib.request.urlopen("https://www.hobbydb.com/api/collectibles/for_sale_search?limit=5&original_site_id=10748&market_id=2") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

I have tried various pieces of code, but everytime I get:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Any ideas how I can parse the price from this JSON?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: Side comment: put your JSON into [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and copy the validated result over. It works even for python list/dict structures that aren't valid JSON. Second, for blocks of code, either use _triple_ backticks, or just highlight the whole code block and use ctrl + k or the `{}` button in the editor

Comment: I am also interested in the hobbyDB API. Do you happen to have access to their documentation for it?

Comment: Where can i find a documentation for hobbyffb api ? I can't find anything about this api on web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer brackets (`[]`) indicate the response returns a list of items. So, you need to loop over the indices of the list, *then* you can access what you're trying to access. Here's how I do it with `requests`

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://www.hobbydb.com/api/collectibles/for_sale_search?limit=5&original_site_id=10748&market_id=2")

#requests has built-in support for json, so no need to import json module
for product in resp.json():
    print(product["price"])
```

Comment: @NamesJoeyWheeler if this answer works please be sure to mark the answer as the solution to the question.

Comment: And more generally, if you run your input through the `type()` function (`type(some_variable)`), it will simply tell you the type.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over json array:

```
for item in data:
    for keys in item.keys():
        print(item[keys])
```

to display only price

```
for item in data:
    print(item['price'])
```

Comment: Why would you iterate a dictionary like that? It's not JSON, it is deserialized to a python dictionary, but `for key, value in data.items()` does this job

Comment: because it's a list of lists

Comment: No it isn't. It's a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is because this JSON object starts with an array (which will be a list once we load it as a Python object).  First, you need to use the `json` library from the standard lib.  Then, you have to access the object using the list index, then the dict keys.

Try this:

```py
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.hobbydb.com/api/collectibles/for_sale_search?limit=5&original_site_id=10748&market_id=2") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
    toy = data[0]
    price = toy['price']
```

Also, keep in mind that the `with` keyword creates a context for parsing the JSON data, so once your script moves on to code outside of this context, you won't be able to access your `price` variable any longer, so you might want to assign or set that value to to another variable created outside of that context.